# 404 error while running jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hi I am receiving the 404 HTTP status while submiting the below jsp.

**HTTP Status 404 - /TestServlet1**
Could you please help me to resolve this error
Note : The person and the dog class were defined
**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="a" action="/TestServlet1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<%

%>
Name = '${person.name}'
Dog = '${person.dog.name}'
</body>
</html>
```

**TestServlet1**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
 */
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TestServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dog g = new Dog();
        g.setName("dogeee");
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setDog(g);
        p.setName("xxx");
        request.setAttribute("person", p);
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>GlobalWeather</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Where did you put index.jsp?  What folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and Third answers are right. Either write action="TestServlet1" or action="/Projectname/TestServlet1". If you put /testServet1 in action, it means you are specifying the path the desired file which in this case is wrong while if you use testservlet1 in action , it means you are searching for a file name testservlet1 in your project to run.

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the URL was not found.  I suspect that you need the web application name in your URL.

So rather than using a form action of:

`/TestServlet1`,

try

```
/name_of_your_web_app/TestServlet1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove tha / in your form action:

```
<form id="a" action="/TestServlet1">
```

change it to

```
<form id="a" action="TestServlet1">
```

In HTML, adding a / means the relative URL and without a slash means absolute URL.  Or better to use the context as mentioned here:

```
<form id="a" action=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/TestServlet1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your contextroot + your servlet name... 
contextRoot usually is the name of your project.

```
action="/nameProject/TestServlet1"
```

I hope this helps you